# Problem solving earthquake problem magnitude logarithims

Tags: calculus

I need help solving a simlar type equation to this..... this one was easy though...
An earthquake off the coast of Vancouver Island was measured at 8.9 on the Richter Scale
and an earthquake off the coast of Alaska was measured at 6.5. How many times more intense, to 
the nearest whole number, was the earthquake off the coast of Vancouver Island than the one off the coast of Alaska?

my solution for this problem was ((10)^8.9/*10^6.5)
251 times more intense

the is the one I' am having problems with.  A major earthquake of magnitude 8.3 is 120 times as intense as a minor earthquake. Determine
     the magnitude, to the nearest tenth, of the minor earthquake.

I think  I should do 10^8.3 / 10^x =12 and solve fore it?  but it has to be a lograthmatic equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subtraction law of exponents:

$$\frac{10^a}{10^b} = 10^{a-b}$$

so that

$$\frac{10^{8.3}}{10^x} = 10^{8.3-x} = 120$$

Therefore

$$8.3 - x = \log_{10}{120} = 2+\log_{10}{1.2} \approx 2.1$$

$$\implies x \approx 6.2$$